# Unable to upload pictures taken by camera

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-volley, multipartform-data

Why is my activity unable to upload pictures taken by camera while it easily uploads the picture picked from the gallery?

The picture uploaded through the gallery is available on the server but the file(picture) taken through the camera is not found on the server after the API hit.

Opening the directory on the server gives 'File not found' error for the file uploaded via camera.

Here is my code:

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static com.app.engage.Interfaces.Keys.userDetails.*;

import com.app.engage.Interfaces.ApiResponse;
import com.app.engage.Interfaces.NetworkConnectivityListener;
import com.app.engage.R;
import com.app.engage.Utilities.ConnectionDetector;
import com.app.engage.Utilities.GetServerData;
import com.app.engage.Utilities.ImageOnlyOptionsDialog;
import com.app.engage.Utilities.ProgressDialog;
import com.app.engage.Utilities.RoleSectDialog;
import com.app.engage.Utilities.RoundCorner;
import com.app.engage.Utilities.SharedPreference_Main;
import com.app.engage.Utilities.Utilities;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.app.engage.Interfaces.OnButtonClicked;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class SignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, ApiResponse.Api_hit, View.OnClickListener {
    private TextView toolbarText;
    public static TextView selections;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private String selected_role = null;
    private String selectedRole = "", selectedOrgType = "";
    public static String selectedNatPriArea = "";
    private ArrayList<String> role_list, org_type, nat_pri_area;
    private ApiResponse apiResponse;
    private ImageView dp;
    private Uri uriFilePath;
    private int REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA = 1002;
    private int REQUEST_PICK_IMAGE = 1003;
    private AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    private TextView upload_dp;
    private AppCompatCheckBox stayLoggedIn;
    private Spinner roleSpinner, organisationTypeSpinner;
    private Button signUp;
    private SharedPreference_Main sharedPreference_main;
    private String mCurrentPhotoPath;
    //   private Utilities utilities;
    private TextView select_nat_pri_area;
    private ConnectionDetector receiver;
    private EditText fullName, email, orgName, password, reEnterPassword;
    private File file = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.blurred_background);  //setting background here
        android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        role_list = new ArrayList<>();                      //arraylist that will hold the roles coming from the server
        org_type = new ArrayList<>();//arraylist that will hold the roles coming from the server
        nat_pri_area = new ArrayList<>();
        sharedPreference_main = new SharedPreference_Main(this);
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.white_back_icon_for_toolbar);
        toolbarText = findViewById(R.id.toolbarText);
        select_nat_pri_area = findViewById(R.id.nat_pri_areaaa);
        toolbarText.setText("Sign Up");
        apiResponse = new ApiResponse(this);
        roleSpinner = findViewById(R.id.select_role_spinner);
        organisationTypeSpinner = findViewById(R.id.organisation_type_spinner);
        fullName = findViewById(R.id.full_name_editText);
        email = findViewById(R.id.email_editText_signUp);
        password = findViewById(R.id.pass_edit_text);
        reEnterPassword = findViewById(R.id.reEnterPword);
        orgName = findViewById(R.id.org_edit_text);
        selections = findViewById(R.id.selectionss);
        signUp = findViewById(R.id.signUp_Button);
        dp = findViewById(R.id.dp);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        select_nat_pri_area.setOnClickListener(this);
        upload_dp = findViewById(R.id.upload_dp);
        dp.setOnClickListener(this);
        selections.setOnClickListener(this);
        upload_dp.setOnClickListener(this);
        // utilities = new Utilities(this);


        receiver = new ConnectionDetector(new NetworkConnectivityListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNetworkConnected()                      //if network connection is available
            {

                if (role_list.size() <= 0 || org_type.size() <= 0 || nat_pri_area.size() <= 0) {
                    getData();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNetworkDisconnected() {
                displayAlert();

            }
        }, this);


        // sharedPreference_main = SharedPreference_Main.getInstance(this);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)    //initialising the AlertDialogue builder
        {
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert);
        } else {
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        }

        roleSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        organisationTypeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(org_type_selection);
        dp.setOnClickListener(this);
        upload_dp.setOnClickListener(this);
//        natPriorityAreaSpinner.setAdapter(adapterSetter(priorityArea));
        signUp.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSetter(ArrayList<String> data)   //to temporarily populate the spinners
    {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, R.layout.custom_spinner, data);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        return adapter;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        receiver.isNetworkAvailable();
        //checkConnection();
    }

    public void signup() {
        if (!validate()) {     //if the conditions in the validate function are not met return
            onSignupFailed();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong sign-up failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "signing up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //  signUp.setEnabled(false);
            progressDialog.progressDialogStart("Please Wait...");
            try {
                apiResponse.hitVolleyMultipartApi(this, "signup", getparams(), prof_pic, file);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        // TODO: Implement your own signup logic here.'
        //  save();


    }


    public void onSignupSuccess()    //if signup is successful
    {
        signUp.setEnabled(true);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, null);
        //Toast.makeText(this, "snkflsndkfl", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        //i.putExtra("Back Functionality", true);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }

    public void onSignupFailed() {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Signup failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        signUp.setEnabled(true);
    }

    public boolean validate()    //to check the entered information
    {
        boolean valid = true;

        String name = fullName.getText().toString();
        String mail = email.getText().toString();
        String pword = password.getText().toString();
        String org_Name = orgName.getText().toString();
        String reEnterPword = reEnterPassword.getText().toString();

        if (name.isEmpty() || name.length() < 3) {
            fullName.setError("at least 3 characters", null);
            valid = false;
        } else {
            fullName.setError(null);
        }
        if (mail.isEmpty() || !android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(mail).matches()) {
            email.setError("enter a valid email address", null);
            valid = false;
        } else {
            email.setError(null);
        }
        if (org_Name.isEmpty()) {
            orgName.setError("Please enter the organisation's name", null);
            valid = false;
        } else {
            orgName.setError(null);
        }


        if (pword.isEmpty() || password.length() < 4 || password.length() > 10) {
            password.setError("between 4 and 10 alphanumeric characters", null);
            valid = false;
        } else {
            password.setError(null);
        }

        if (reEnterPword.isEmpty() || reEnterPassword.length() < 4 || reEnterPassword.length() > 10 || !(reEnterPword.equals(pword))) {
            reEnterPassword.setError("Password Do not match", null);
            valid = false;
        } else {
            reEnterPassword.setError(null);

        }

        return valid;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                selectedRole = "Facilitator";
                break;
            case 1:
                selectedRole = "Provider Administrator";
                break;
            case 2:
                selectedRole = "Provider Executive";
                break;
            case 3:
                selectedRole = "School PLD Administrator";
                break;
            case 4:
                selectedRole = "MOE National Priority";
                break;
            case 5:
                selectedRole = "Senior Leadership";
                break;
            case 6:
                selectedRole = "Teacher";
                break;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }

    AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener org_type_selection = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()    //for organisation type selection
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    selectedOrgType = "Education";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    selectedOrgType = "IT";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    selectedOrgType = "Medical";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    selectedOrgType = "";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    selectedOrgType = "";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    selectedOrgType = "";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    selectedOrgType = "";
                    break;

            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.dp:
            case R.id.upload_dp:
                ImageOnlyOptionsDialog imageOnlyOptionsDialog = new ImageOnlyOptionsDialog();
                imageOnlyOptionsDialog.setonButtonClickListener(new OnButtonClicked() {
                    @Override
                    public void onButtonCLick(int buttonId) {
                        switch (buttonId) {
                            case R.id.btnCamera:
                                startCamera();
                                break;
                            case R.id.btnGallery:
                                pickFromGallery();
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
                imageOnlyOptionsDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), ImageOnlyOptionsDialog.class.getSimpleName());

                break;

            case R.id.signUp_Button:
                signup();
                break;

            case R.id.nat_pri_areaaa:
            case R.id.selectionss:
                Bundle data = new Bundle();
                data.putStringArrayList("pri_areas", nat_pri_area);
                RoleSectDialog roleSectDialog = new RoleSectDialog();
                roleSectDialog.setArguments(data);
                roleSectDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), RoleSectDialog.class.getSimpleName());
                roleSectDialog.setonButtonClickListener(new OnButtonClicked() {
                    @Override
                    public void onButtonCLick(int buttonId) {
                        switch (buttonId) {
                            case R.id.k:
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }


    public void startCamera() {
        PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager();
        if (packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            File mainDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyFolder/tmp");
            if (!mainDirectory.exists())
                mainDirectory.mkdirs();

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            uriFilePath = Uri.fromFile(new File(mainDirectory, "IMG_" + calendar.getTimeInMillis() + ".jpeg"));
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent1.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriFilePath);
            startActivityForResult(intent1, REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA);
        }
    }

    public void pickFromGallery()            //this is the intent creation for picking image from gallery
    {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), REQUEST_PICK_IMAGE);

    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)            //this receives the intent's result
    {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                try {
                    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(uriFilePath.getPath());
                    int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                            ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

                    switch (orientation) {
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                            matrix.postRotate(90);
                            break;
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                            matrix.postRotate(180);
                            break;
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                            matrix.postRotate(270);
                            break;
                    }
                    String filePath = getRealPathFromURI(uriFilePath);
                    file = new File(new URI("file://" + filePath.replace(" ", "%20")));//photo is file type that is global
                    Glide.with(this)
                            .load(file)
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.upload_image)
                            .into(dp);
//                    getImageDetails(photo);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_PICK_IMAGE) {

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                String selectedImagePath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
                Toast.makeText(this, selectedImagePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try {
                    file = new File(new URI("file://" + selectedImagePath.replace(" ", "%20")));
                    Glide.with(this).load(file).placeholder(R.drawable.upload_image)
                            .into(dp);
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        }
    }

    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
        if (uri == null) {
            return null;
        }
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        return uri.getPath();
    }


    public HashMap<String, String> getparams() {                            //parameters passed while hitting the API
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put(rulee, "sign_up");
        params.put(emaill, email.getText().toString());
        params.put(word, password.getText().toString());
        params.put(f_name, fullName.getText().toString());
        params.put(n_p_a, selections.getText().toString());
        params.put(or_name, orgName.getText().toString());
        params.put(or_type, selectedOrgType);
        Toast.makeText(this, selectedRole, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        params.put(rolId, selectedRole);
        return params;
    }

    @Override
    public void response(String responseObject, String method_call)        //this gets the response when API is hit
    {
        progressDialog.dismissDialog();
        try {
            JSONObject response = new JSONObject(responseObject);
            if (response.getString("flag").equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject("response");
                sharedPreference_main.setUserName(object.getString(f_name));
                sharedPreference_main.setUserEmail(object.getString(emaill));
                sharedPreference_main.setUserOrganisation(object.getString(or_name));
                sharedPreference_main.setUserRole(object.getString(rol));
                sharedPreference_main.setOrgType(object.getString(or_type));
                sharedPreference_main.setNPA(object.getString(n_p_a));
                sharedPreference_main.setUserProfilePic(object.getString(prof_pic));
                onSignupSuccess();    //if everything works out call the home activity
            } else if (response.getString("flag").equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                String resp = response.getString("response");
                builder.setTitle("Error:");          //building up the dialog
                builder.setMessage(resp);
                displayAlert(resp);
            } else if (response.getString("flag").equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                // Toast.makeText(this, response.getString("flag"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                JSONArray data = response.getJSONArray("message");

                if (data.length() > 0) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject inData = data.getJSONObject(i);
                        if (inData.has("role_name")) {
                            role_list.add(inData.getString("role_name"));
                        } else if (inData.has("organisation_type")) {
                            org_type.add(inData.getString("organisation_type"));
                        } else if (inData.has("prior_name")) {

                            nat_pri_area.add(inData.getString("prior_name"));
                        }
                        //     N_P_A.add(inData.getString("prior_name"));
                    }
                }
                if (role_list.size() > 0) {
                    // String[] role = role_list.toArray(new String[role_list.size()]);
                    roleSpinner.setAdapter(adapterSetter(role_list));
                }
                if (org_type != null) {
                    //  String organisationType[] =org_type.toArray(new String[org_type.size()]);
                    organisationTypeSpinner.setAdapter(adapterSetter(org_type));
                }

                //   String[] priorityArea = org_type.toArray(new String[org_type.size()]);

                //
            }


            // onSignupSuccess();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void error(String error) {
        progressDialog.dismissDialog();
        Toast.makeText(this, error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    private void displayAlert(final String code) {
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                fullName.setText("");
                email.setText("");
                password.setText("");
                orgName.setText("");

            }
        }).show();


    }

    private void displayAlert()   //overloaded function
    {
        builder.setTitle("No internet connection");
        builder.setTitle("Please switch on the internet");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                //    checkConnection();
                if (receiver.isNetworkAvailable()) {
                    dialogInterface.c**strong text**ancel();
                } else {
                    displayAlert();
                }

            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                //  checkConnection();
                dialogInterface.cancel();
            }
        }).show();


    }

    public void getData() {
        GetServerData getServerData = new GetServerData(this);
        getServerData.getRoles();
    }
}
```

Note: 
Language version - Java
Target SDK -23

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What issue you are exactly facing

Comment: the issue is that the pic taken via camera is not found on the server after the API hit whereas a gallery pic is successfully stored and available on the server.

Comment: you are saying not found on server and then you are saying it's available on server

Comment: please explain clearly

Comment: I said the volley multipart is able to upload "phone gallery pictures" on the server but it is unable to upload a picture taken through the camera. I am able to find the picture "uploaded via gallery" on the server but the picture "taken through phone camera" is not being uploaded there.

Comment: Ok,Let me check how i can help you

Comment: Thanks..please do provide tips to improve my way of writing code ...

Comment: check the mode of connection of camera - Is it in media mode? that would help do file operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening because the permissions were not being provided to the application while running it on the smartphone. Newer versions of Android require the apps to be granted permissions from within the smartphone.

Answer (score 0):

Use this and upvote after your issue gets resolve.

```
    private File profilePic;
    private Uri photoFileUri;


    /**
     * Method below will work for Camera Intent.
     */
    private void clickPicture() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

            try {
                photoFile = AppUtils.getInstance().createImageFile(); // Create the File where the photo should go
                outputFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(SignUpActivity.this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_IMAGE_REQUEST);
            } catch (IOException io) {
                io.printStackTrace(); // Error occurred while creating the File
            }
            //outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);//At this Uri the image captured will get saved.
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {

                case AppConstants.MediaConstants.REQUEST_CAPTURE_IMAGE:
                    profilePic = new            File(AppUtils.getInstance().getRealPathFromURI(photoFileUri, mActivity));
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Use this method below directly in your classs**

```
/**
     * method to get real path from uri
     *
     * @param contentURI
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI, Context context) {
        String result;
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
            result = contentURI.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            result = cursor.getString(idx);
            cursor.close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

create "provide_paths.xml" file in folder name "xml" in res directory and add code below in it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />

</paths>
```